# Strange behavior when loading mdi winform c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I´m getting a strange behavior in a c# MDI WinForms application. When i open a specific form together with any other form, this specific form locks up. Somehow its grouping the ControlBox of both forms into one, looking like this:

[image]

As the forms has stopped responding, its not closeable and has stopped painting:

[image]

The strange part is that any other combination of forms works fine. The forms gets loaded on top of each other and the application does not freeze.
But i can not figure out whats different about this form compared to the others. All settings are identical.
This is the code in the main MDIform that initiate new child forms, its called from a ToolStrip Button.Click event:

```
    private void OpenForm(object sender)
    {
        if (sender == null) return;            
        ToolStripMenuItem itemSender = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        try
        { 
            WinForm mapping = (WinForm)itemSender.Tag;

            if (!FormList.ContainsKey(mapping.FormName))
            {
                Type frmType = Type.GetType(string.Format("OrderAssist.Forms.{0}", mapping.FormName));
                if (frmType != null)
                {
                    Form newForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(frmType);
                    if (!newForm.IsDisposed)
                    {
                        newForm.Name = mapping.FormName;
                        newForm.Tag = itemSender;
                        newForm.MdiParent = this;
                        newForm.Show();
                        newForm.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
                        newForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(newForm_FormClosing);
                        FormList.Add(newForm.Name, newForm);
                        itemSender.Checked = true;
                        newForm.Activate();                         
                    }
                }
                else
                    itemSender.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
                FormList[mapping.FormName].Activate();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Exceptions.ProgramException(e, Settings.User.ID, "Exception occured while opening a form.");
            if (itemSender != null)
                itemSender.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

To make the matter stranger, if i populate this form that locks with data and click on some controls inside, before opening another form, the error does not occur.

Im out of ideas of what to try next.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but your picture just reminded me of this one: *http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/274060_700b.jpg* :D

Comment: I can't see anything, but I'd look for into any recursion anywhere in your MDI code. It really seems like you're opening the same form MANY times and that is what "locking" your application. from what you describing it could be some event handling that's being called so many times.

Comment: It is a bug in the Winforms adapter code for MDI.  This happens when you create a child window in the MDI main form constructor.  Use the Load event (OnLoad) instead.  The dead painting is probably something else.

Comment: I have double checked that only 2 forms are open, one of the images is the look of one of the forms hanging (stop painting). Also OpenForm() is called from a ButtonClick event, no way near the Constructor.

Comment: The forms that hangs/crashed did load another FormDialog in constructor, but i have commented out that code and the forms still hangs. If i pause the debugger it stop on: Application.Run(new FormMain());, dosent that indicate that it isnt my code locking my form (like a bad loop)?

Comment: I know this is an old story, but have you ever found a solution ? I am getting the same freezing mdi child form. The freezing form is not in "Application.OpenForms" or "this.MdiChildren" so no way to find and close it...

Answer (score 0):

```
newForm.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

The above line is called for all your controls, which results in the control boxes being grouped together.

As for that form freezing up, you need to post the code of the child form that causes the form freeze. Then I can assist you further.

Comment: This partially helps; if I keep the forms WindowState away from Maximized it does not hang. But even if I don't create it Maximized all needed is for the user to press the maximize button while another form is open and suddenly it hangs.